# Modifying Rails: How do advanced users find out what needs to be changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using Rails for a few months now, and I'm quite comfortable writing up a project & manipulating Rails to my needs, etc.

Recently I've been trying to get a little more advanced, so I've attempted to modify/add to the existing rails codebase: add new form helper methods, add a responds_to :pdf method, etc...and I've been having a lot of problems.

The difficulty is learning which code I need to modify; where that code is located, and how to ensure I don't miss related code in other files. I'm guessing there's a way people learn to do this, but at the moment I'm mostly just guessing-and-hoping.

I guess my question is, how do Rails folks go about learning where the code they need to modify is edited & the approach to editing it? It seems like it's just something you need to know from prior familiarity, but I'm guessing there has to be a simple method for understanding where (and what) to edit.

Any ideas appreciated...cheers

Comment: What you've described is pretty accurate for what I do!

Comment: nice question, i'd like to know how other people do. I just use the [API doc](http://apidock.com/rails) to get a peek on the source code until i understand the mechanics. Another way to gain knowledge... is stack overflow ! when i started learning rails, i used to scan all rails-related questions, and tried to find the answer myself. Doing this, i learned a lot about rails internals.
however, i'm not sure this question belongs here. Maybe on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend Jose Valim's [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications)

You go through advanced projects, building out the types of engines and customizations that will take you to the next level in your Rails development.

From the site:

> This book will help you understand Rails 3’s inner workings, including
>   generators, template handlers, internationalization, routing, and
>   responders.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read Crafting & enjoyed it, but I didn't get a whole lot of insight into a methodology for understanding unfamiliar parts of the framework. A methodology for creating gems, yes - but where the framework was cracked open, there seemed to be more of an approach of 'just type this in' as opposed to how one would gain an understanding of the parts of the framework being modified.

Comment: @unclaimedbaggage If you mastered Crafting, then it's time for you to dive in. Run the rake tests, make changes, run the tests again. Repeat. There's no guided tour at that level.

Answer (score -2):

What you are asking for is how `MVC` works. Basicly you can say:

1.) Put logic to the model! The model is the pivot everything turns around.

2.) The Controller is a middleman between the model and the view. You dont put any logic here that isnt related to selecting data from the database that should be displayed in the view. If you use one selection logic more than once create a `scope` in the Model and use it in the Controller.

3.) The View is only there to display things! You dont put any logic here! All the logic comes from the model and the data comes from the controller. The only logic your using here are loops through arrays of data that should be displayed.

Then you have some things missing. If you have a task that is related to an external service like lets say a SOAP Service you write a class for that too! Just whithout using ActiveRecord::Base inheritance like its generated by the scaffolder. You can call this Class in other models. Dont put this to the controller or copy the code in every class that needs it! Stay `DRY` (Dont Repeat Yourself). Just write a class for it and include it in the other models!

Another thing thats a Database basic: Dont store data that could be calculated from other fields from the database! You can add methods that calculate the stuff you need but dont start with duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not quite what I was after. I'm comfortable using rails & integrating ruby scripts. It's extending/overriding the framework itself that scares me. ;-)